# How to design a index field that insertable and reorderable

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, insert

If I want to design a table like a book, book have so many chapters, chapters can **order by** other field like `created_time`

```
id | chapter_name
1  |  aa
2  |  cc
3  |  dd
```

I can order these record output like:

> aa, cc, dd

In condition of the book have too many chapters, if author want to insert a chapter between of exist chapters

There are two confuses in this condition:

1. How to design it so I can insert a record `bb` output like:

> aa, bb, cc, dd

2. How to design it so I can reorder `dd` output like:

> aa, dd, cc

Thanks a lot, If I thinking was wrong in the beginning, please point out

Comment: Can you show us your desired output?  By the way, in general there is no order in a MySQL table.  The only order which exists happens when you query it using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: if you don' t adjust `order_id` how it can be between `aa` and `cc`? DO you want to change the`id` of this table? If these don't need, you can just use `order by` on `name`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, I've added desire output, yep! I want to order these data by other field, like `order_id` or something

Comment: I think this question is not answerable and makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to change your `order_id` to a floating point value, so you can insert/update it to say 1.5. Or you'll need to use a bigger number space like 1000, 2000, 3000, so you can put entries in between e.g. 1500.

If you want integer numbering you can use your order-by column to generate dynamic ordering with `row_number` etc, e.g.

```
SELECT chapter_name, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY order_id) FROM my_table;
```

Alternately, might you be confused about how database tables work and expecting it to maintain an ordering with no `ORDER BY` clause? Because they don't work like that. The database can return rows in any order it feels like unless you supply an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thank a lot, I thought it same as you before, like design a book, book have so many chapter, chapter have index, but If author want to insert a chapter, that is the problem

Comment: So what do you think now? I still don't really understand your question, everyone is trying to guess what you actually mean.

Comment: Sorry, I think my description is not clear, just want to know how to design that table in case like book chapters, `order_id` or `created_time` is the solution to index record in create time, but how to adjust index of one of these record in future?

Comment: @Kcat Have an ordering column and renumber later values. Or use something divisible so you can insert values in between. You can also use `row_number()`  (see above).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hard code the values

For the first query

Update table_name
Set id=4 and order_id=4
WHERE name='dd';

Update table_name
Set id=3 and order_id=3
WHERE name='cc';

Insert into (id, name, order_id)  values (2,'bb',2);

For the second query

Update table_name
Set id=2 and order_id=2
WHERE name='dd';

(second query is when their are no bb record in name) after this just to order by order_id